# Can't suggest edit on a question

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I've tried removing the XHTML tag and the _L signature in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282603/how-many-div-tags-are-too-much).

After clicking *Save Edits*, all seems fine until I check my activity box under my profile and notice my suggested edit is inexistent.

After hitting Back on the browser a few times until I land on the editing URL of that question, I receive a "Page not found" error.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you force a reload? With the datacenter switch, perhaps some crucial JS resource didn't load in your browser.

Comment: Can you try proposing another change to the question?  As a user with full edit privs, I was able to make the changes you wanted without a problem.  (I've then rolled back the edit so we can keep poking at it.)

Comment: "This site is currently in read-only mode". Probably glitches due to the migration.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Hadn't noticed this message, that probably explains it. Thanks